# Is it safe to install CCleaner now?

Tags: malware

About 4 or 5 weeks ago, i read a article on THN(the hacker news) that the ccleaner servers were hacked to distribute malware and as a result millions of computers were affected who had downloaded and installed ccleaner in month of August. I have also ccleaner installed on my older pc which i had downloaded before August and my pc is not infected.But I buyed a new laptop now, then it will be safe to install ccleaner now?

Comment: Yes it is safe to install now.

Comment: You may want to reconsider the actual use of ccleaner. Logs and cache don't just 'accumulate', they are either there for a good reason (cache) or are automatically wiped under disk pressure/rollover (logs).

Comment: @Sirens as you said logs and cache are there for a good reason, then how the performance of a machine can be enhanced by wiping this out? As most people people thinks (including me) that ccleaner can make our pc even faster.

Comment: @daya It doesn't -- purely placebo. Most likely it'll just make things worse since without cache the device has to rebuild the caches. There are some unique, troubleshooting instances where it'll make sense to clear caches (if for example you see CPU pinned at 100 by a certain system process) otherwise it does worse than nothing. Just because most people think it does something doesn't mean it actually does anything

Comment: @Sirens thanks for your explanation, the conclusion is we don't really need ccleaner, am I right?

Comment: @daya Right. Windows has been designed to handle this on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to install ...

It is nearly impossible to be sure that some software is safe to install. It can always contain a back door, have bugs in it which might be exploitable from a remote system or similar.

All one can say that the specific problem with CCleaner was fixed according to Avast and that currently no other problems are publicly known with this software. If you consider this safe enough is up to you.